# Number Recognition from a binary image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I'm working on number recognition from image using matlab, i have transformed the colored image into binary image then i extracted every object including numbers from this binary image, my question is What's the best way to do to recognize the numbers from extracted images?

[image]

- I read about HOG but i can't normalize the color and gamma from this image.
- when i applied ocr on each extracted image, it fails for all.

Comment: Take a look at [***this***](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html)